# Unit Testing and Code Coverage Frameworks for Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing

I'm planning to write couple applications for iPhone and wonder if there are any Unit Testing and Code Coverage Frameworks for Objective-C?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For unit testing iPhone apps there is [OCTest](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html) or Googles [iPhoneUnitTesting](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/iPhoneUnitTesting)

For a mocking framework you can use [OCMock](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/OCMock/). [Here](http://iamthewalr.us/blog/2008/11/ocmock-and-the-iphone/)  is the guide to getting it to work with the iPhone.

[GCov](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html) can be used for code coverage.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to GCov that would work with LLVM?