# How to determine code coverage for an Objective-C program?

Tags: objective-c, code-coverage

When writing `jUnit` tests for `Java`, for example, tools like `EclEmma` allows easy view of how much coverage a program has and what areas of code remain without test coverage.

[image]

**Does anything like this exists for Objective-C? How can one determine code coverage for your Objective-C iOS application?**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646641/unit-testing-and-code-coverage-frameworks-for-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of LLVM, the compiler Apple uses, [support code coverage reports](http://mattrajca.com/blog/2011/08/14/llvm/).